# jQuery scroll to anchor with variable speed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a very basic HTML site with a few anchor tags. On click each anchor leads to the other, using a little bit of smooth scroll with this function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {  
        e.preventDefault(); var target = this.hash; var $target = $(target);
        $('html, body').stop().animate(
            {
                'scrollTop': $target.offset().top - 300
            },
            900,
            'swing',
            function () {
                window.location.hash = target - 300 ;
            }
        );
    });
});
```

The gaps between the anchors will be quite big and I am trying to figure out a way to get the speed to vary - when clicked on an anchor, to start slower, than speed up, when close to the next anchor to slow down again before it stops.

Could not find any JQuery docs on it, does someone has a suggestion?

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/koteva/ovf9ywb3/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would want to use an easing function to handle this. By default, jQuery only handles `swing` easing, which you have already passed into your `animate` function. However, you can include additional easing functions with a plugin.

George Smith has a lightweight js plugin for download that may help you, called [jquery.easing.1.3.js](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/). I think `easeInOutQuart` sounds like the closest thing to what you are looking for

Here is a [demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ovf9ywb3/3/)

Answer (score 0):

By including [jQuery UI](https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js) (after jQuery) you will be able to use the easings listed [here](https://jqueryui.com/easing/)

Your code should look like:

```
$('html, body').stop().animate(
    {
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top - 300
    },
    900,
    'easeInOutCubic',
    function () {
        window.location.hash = target - 300 ;
    }
);
```